# tempstore.private not working in openIDConnect client

Tags: users, 9

I am getting some licence info via retrieveUserInfo in the openIDConnect custom client login process. Ideally i want to write it to the session but opted for the "tempstore.private" since it seems to be the drupal way.

in retrieveUserInfo I am getting the

```
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('tempstore.private')->get('sessionlike');
```

.. going through the licences and detecting the right ones and then i set:

```
 $tempstore->set('has_plus', true);
```

however retrieving the value in the custom block with

```
 $tempstore->get('has_plus')
```

comes up empty.

Do I need to apply the tempstore changes somehow ? Could not find anything on that.

Comment: You may be misdiagnosing it - your block may be cached. Try setting the value in the tempstore, clearing the cache/registry, then refreshing the page with the block to see if the value shows correct.

Comment: sadly the whole thing is running in debug mode now. And there is no caching. I am suspecting that the session might geht reset AFTER the retrieveUserInfo because it is a login after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally i want to write it to the session but opted for the
> "tempstore.private" since it seems to be the drupal way.

I think you've read some old blog post advertising Tempstore as replacement for the superglobal $_SESSION. They were wrong, it was replaced by the Symfony Session object.

To make the right choice between Tempstore and Session you need to consider the use case. See [What is the difference between \Drupal::request()->getSession() and \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278686/what-is-the-difference-between-drupalrequest-getsession-and-drupalser)

The best Drupal way performance-wise would be adding a `session` cache context to the block. Blocks with this cache context are automatically lazy-loaded through BigPipe.

```
public function build() {
  $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
  $build = [
   '#plain_text' => $session->get('value'),
  ];
  $build['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session';
  return $build;
}
```

This also helps with [your comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/315164/tempstore-private-not-working-in-openidconnect-client#comment403336_315164), session data does survive a user login.

Comment: That does not answer my question but thanks, i will try using the session.

Comment: I've added more context why I've suggested this solution.

Comment: Thank you. Now this a complete answer. Due to your suggestion i found the other answer as well and was about to recommend you add it. I will accept this now.